# How to send field value from one page to another using php session?

Tags: php, session

As i am a beginner and i am stucked in a situation. Note: Email sending code present in thankyou.php

My problem is i have to store the Date selected and pass to another page after completion of payment through paypal. I have tried php session but dont where i am lagging.

After success full transaction i am getting all the details in $_POST from the paypal like txn_id, payer_email etc but i am not getting the date which i selected in form.

Please help me to the right direction.

I am working on paypal integration and i have 1 form in which two fields are present (index.php)

1. Select date
2. No. of tickets

Code index.php :

```
    <?php

@session_start(); 
    $var_value = $_POST['eventdate'];
    $_SESSION['eventdate'] = $var_value;
    echo $_SESSION['eventdate'];
?>

<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/r" method="post">
                      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" id="tbl_paypal_form">
                        <tr>
                          <td colspan="2"><div id="ticket_amount">£10 per person</div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Select Event Date <span class="mandatory">*</span></td>
                          <td><select name="eventdate" id="eventdate" class="form_field">
                              <option value="">Select Date</option>
                              <option value="Sat 14 July 2012">Sat 14 July 2012</option>
                              <option value="Sun 15 July 2012">Sun 15 July 2012</option>
                              <option value="Mon 16 July 2012">Mon 16 July 2012</option>
                            </select></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>No. of Tickets <span class="mandatory">*</span></td>
                          <td><input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" class="form_field">
                          <span style="color:#bbb; font-size:11px; padding-top:5px;">For ex: 4</span>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td colspan="2"><?php
                                if(!empty($errorMessage)) 
                                {
                                    echo("<div id='validation_error'>");
                                    echo("<p class='error_message'>There was an error with your form:</p>\n");
                                    echo("<ul class='error_message'>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
                                    echo("</div>");
                                }
                            ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td><img src="images/paypal.gif" /></td>
                          <td><input type="image" src="images/btn_paypal.gif" border="0" name="formsubmit" value="Submit" onclick="return ValidateForm();" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">                              
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                      <input type="hidden" name="business" value="gala@iskconcoventry.com">
                      <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
                      <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Gala Charity Show Tickets">
                      <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10">
                      <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.vyx.com/gala/thankyou.php">
                      <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.xyx.com/gala/thankyou.php">
                      <input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Return to The Store">
                      <!--<input type="hidden" name="eventdate" value="<?php echo $_POST['eventdate'];?>">-->
                    </form>
```

Code: thankyou.php

```
<?php

session_start();
$ticketdate = $_SESSION['eventdate'];
//echo $_SESSION['eventdate'];
echo $ticketdate;
?>

<pre style="background:#fff;">
<?php print_r($_POST);?>
</pre>

<?php


if($_POST['txn_id'] != "") 
{
    $mail_subject='Ticket Booked for Gala Charity event';
    $mail_body.= 'Hello Dear, <br><br>';
    $mail_body.= 'Below are the ticket booking details for Gala Charity event. <br><br>';
    $mail_body.= '<b>Booking Date : </b>'. $ticketdate .'<br><br>';
    //$mail_body.= '<b>Booking Date : </b>'.trim($_POST['eventdate']).'<br><br>';
    $mail_body.= '<b>Number of tickets buyed : </b>'.trim($_POST['quantity']).'<br><br>';

    $mail_body.= '<b>Transaction ID : </b>'.trim($_POST['txn_id']).'<br><br>';
    $mail_body.= '<b>First Name : </b>'.trim($_POST['first_name']).'<br><br>';
    $mail_body.= '<b>Last Name : </b>'.trim($_POST['last_name']).'<br><br>';
    $mail_body.= '<b>Payers Email  : </b>'.trim($_POST['payer_email']).'<br><br>';
    $mail_body.= '<b>Payment Date : </b>'.trim($_POST['payment_date']).'<br><br>';

    $mail_body.= '<b>Address Name : </b>'.trim($_POST['address_name']).'<br><br>';
    $mail_body.= '<b>Street : </b>'.trim($_POST['address_street']).'<br><br>';
    $mail_body.= '<b>Zip : </b>'.trim($_POST['address_zip']).'<br><br>';
    $mail_body.= '<b>State : </b>'.trim($_POST['address_state']).'<br><br>';
    $mail_body.= '<b>Country Code : </b>'.trim($_POST['address_country_code']).'<br><br>';


    $mail_body.= '<b>Item Name : </b>'.trim($_POST['item_name']).'<br><br>';
    $mail_body.= '<b>Total Amount Paid : </b>'.trim($_POST['mc_currency']).'&nbsp;'.trim($_POST['mc_gross']).'<br><br>';

    $mail_from=$_POST['payer_email'];
    $mail_to = "myname@example.com";

    //$mail_reply_to = $mail_from;
    $mail_headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\nFrom: $mail_from\r\nReply-to: $mail_reply_to\r\n";
    @mail($mail_to, $mail_subject, $mail_body, $mail_headers);

}
?>
```

Comment: Where are you actually saving the value to SESSION?

Comment: hello lng , please see the code for session i added in index.php code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use paypal's custom data field to send and receive additional values on payments. Simply add another input to your form

```
<input name="custom" type="hidden" value="" />
```

If you need to send two or more values you can join them with a separator like `|` then process them when you get them back from paypal.

EDIT

Change your form to

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/r" method="post" onsubmit="buildCustomVar()">
```

Add a little javascript to your page before the closing `</body>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function buildCustomVar()
    {
        var custom = $('select[name="eventdate"]').val() + "|" + $('input[name="quantity"]').val();
        $('input[name="custom"]').val(custom);
    }
</script>
```

On the server side just simply explode the value you get

```
$temp = explode("|", $_POST['custom']);
$date = $temp[0];
$quantity = $temp[1];
```

Comment: can you please elaborate in my case how to pass the values?

Comment: Dear thanks a lot for saving my day. I am getting the out put and your answer and approach is correct i appreciate your efforts. I Still have a query that how to accomplish same with Sessions?

Answer (score 1):

chage your form to

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/r" method="post" onsubmit="buildCustomVar()">
```

add javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
enter code here
    function buildCustomVar()
    {
        var custom = $('select[name="eventdate"]').val() + "|" + $('input[name="quantity"]').val();
        $('input[name="custom"]').val(custom);
    }
</script>
```